# How to do an SQL Sum(*) with Django ORM?

Tags: django, postgresql

Hello and excuse my english

I would like to do this SQL query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

equivalent with Django 1.8 ORM

Comment: The title and the question don't match...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do `COUNT(*)` you do:

```
Model.objects.all().count()
```

[Django doc about count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#count).

To do sum on certain field you do:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
Model.objects.aggregate(Sum('id'))
```

[Django doc about sum()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum).